# How can I click inside a bootstrap 5 dropdown without closing it, with React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm building a semi-complex nav bar using with bootstrap 5 and ReactJS. For this, I'm using a dropdown menu.

When I click inside of the dropdown anywhere (even if the part I'm clicking on is just plain text and not a link), the dropdown closes and I have no idea why. I've tried adding the `data-bs-auto-close` prop and have set it to `inside`, `outside` and `false` and it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Here is a very basic code example of my problem - the left side of the dropdown (where it just has a small header saying **Hi**) shouldn't trigger the dropdown to close:

https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-5-playground-forked-drrly7?file=/index.html

Any help here would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an old version of bootstrap. Use the latest version. It will work. I've tried in your codesandbox.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction

Comment: I'm using bootstrap version 5.2.3. Surely this isn't a bug which relates to all versions < 5.3

Comment: @gb992 in your sandbox it's 5.0.0-beta3

Comment: Apologies @Mizan - yes, in the sandbox it's 5.0.0, in my project locally it's using 5.2.3, and I still have the issue.

Comment: I apologise again- I updated the bootstrap version to 5.3 and it solved my problem! Thank you